# Basic manipulation of algebraic expressions

Tags: coq

I'm still missing the basic technique to manipulate algebraic expressions by adding the same value to both sides. For instance, if the present goal is `a + b < a + 5`, how do I transform it to `b < 5` as one would do in a pen-paper proof? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of things, you need to use the lemmata that already prove this.
Most of these are proven in `Arith`.
If you type

```
From Coq Require Import Arith.
Search "+" "<".
```

Coq will tell you of lemmata that talk about both addition and the 'lower than' relation.
In particular you will find

```
plus_lt_compat_l: forall n m p : nat, n < m -> p + n < p + m
```

So that

```
Goal forall a b, a + b < a + 5.
  intros a b.
  apply plus_lt_compat_l.
```

will indeed leave you to prove `b < 5`.

More often than not, you do not really want to go through the search and instead use some automation. For this `lia` is recommended.

```
From Coq Require Import Lia.

Goal forall a b, a + b < a + 5.
  intros a b.
  cut (b < 5).
  { lia. }
  (* The remaining goal is b < 5 *)
```

`lia` is a tactic that solves many arithmetic problems like those.

Comment: You can find lemmas like this with `Search (?A  + ?L < ?A + ?R).` There's another one in `PeanoNat`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's set up this goal. Although `nat` and `<` are predefined, you need `Require Import Arith` for many basic theorems about arithmetic.

```
Require Import Arith.
Goal forall a b : nat, b < 5 -> a + b < a + 5.
  intros.
```

First let's see how to find the right lemma from the library manually. We can search the available lemmas whose conclusion has the right shape.

```
SearchPattern (_+_ < _+_).
```

This returns many lemmas, one of which happens to have the right shape (were the left-hand sides of the `+` operator are the same on both sides): `plus_lt_compat_l`. So we can apply this lemma.

```
  apply plus_lt_compat_l.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

Note that sometimes there might be a lemma with `<` but not one with `<=`, and `SearchPattern` won't find that. In such cases, `unfold lt in *.` to expand all uses of `<` to `<=` might help, possibly followed by additional rewriting to move the `S` around.

Of course finding the right lemma each time is tedious, so there are ways to automate this search. One of the ways is to use a hint database. There's a built-in database called `arith`, which includes this lemma. `auto with arith` tries to apply any combination of lemmas from the `arith` database up to a certain depth. The variant `eauto with arith`, not needed here, would also try to invent intermediate variables.

```
Require Import Arith.
Goal forall a b : nat, b < 5 -> a + b < a + 5.
  intros.
  auto with arith.
Qed.
```

For arithmetic specifically, there are “just solve this” targets, such as `lia` (or `omega` in older versions of Coq), which can solve any inequation involving additions of variables and constants.

```
Require Import Omega.
Goal forall a b : nat, b < 5 -> a + b < a + 5.
  intros.
  omega.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, Gilles. Very educative.

Comment: `omega` is deprecated and `lia` should be used instead.